# How to specify a branch in "sbt new"?

Tags: scala, github, sbt, giter8

When using [sbt new](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/sbt-new-and-Templates.html#Trying+new+command), I can initialize a new project based on the default branch of a github project containing a [giter8](http://www.foundweekends.org/giter8/) template.

Is it also possible to use a template from a branch other than the default one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The working solution is as follows:

`sbt new foo/foo.g8 --branch bar-branch`